# lxml will return empty lisy but requests_html will return wanted result

Tags: python

I wrote two codes one with requests and lxml other with request_html. The code with requests and lxml will return an empty list while the code with request_thml will return the wanted result.

code 1:

```
from lxml import html

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/OnePlus-Glacial-Unlocked-Android-Smartphone/dp/B08723759H/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1624692877&sr=8-1'

page = requests.get(url)

content = html.fromstring(page.text)

price = content.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]')

print(price)


#output is always 
#[]
```

code 2 :

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/OnePlus-Glacial-Unlocked-Android-Smartphone/dp/B08723759H/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1624692877&sr=8-1'

session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1)

title = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]', first=True)

print(title)

#output

#OnePlus 8 Glacial Green,​ 5G Unlocked Android Smartphone U.S Version, 8GB RAM+128GB Storage, 90Hz Fluid Display,Triple Camera, with Alexa Built-in,
```

Comment: Your URL returns a 503 error when trying to run the `lxml` code, but it seems likely that this is the same problem as for pretty much any web-scraping question on SO: `requests` doesn't execute JavaScript, while `requests_html` downloads and runs a Chromium browser, which will. Likely, the content you're trying to grab is modified or added by JavaScript on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was trying to change from ```requests_html``` to ```requests``` because ```resuests_html``` will load the page every time a function is called.  But thanks anyway.